Is there any reference to linear calendar time in the canonical scriptures?
Time, as measured by the calendar is seldom mentioned in Hindu scripture.
There is a lot of research going on about dating scriptural events based on events like eclipses, positions of planets relative to constellations etc. that are mentioned in scripture, but there is no consensus among different researchers.
Alexander's invasion in 327 b.c is considered to be the earliest firm date in Indian history.  Later firm dates are available in accounts of Chinese visitors and Buddhist and Jain scriptures.
The Indian linear calendar, the Samvat system, is believed to have started in 57 BCE, making it one of the oldest known calendar systems.
Are there any scriptural references to absolute dates based on the Samvat or other systems?

Hindu calendar is of 2 types - lunar & solar. The solar year is described as the time taken by the sun to travel once through each of the 12 rasis, with the time of presence of the sun in a single rasi being defined as the month. The lunar moth is defined as the time between 2 successive new/full moons, & 12 such months constitute a lunar year. The Mai difference between Hindu calenders & the Western calendars is that the latter are tropical I.e using the position of sun at particular point on the horizon as reference frame

whereas the former are sidereal I.e use the position of naksatras in the sky as the reference frame to determine the position of the sun. However, there is no unified consensus on selecting a year 1. The Samvat you referred is actually the Vikrama Samvat, which is lunar-based & widely followed in North & West India. South & East India follow the Saka Samvat, which started at 78 CE. Then there is also the Kaliyuga Samvat, which is less popular than the other two. There is also a system of Barhaspatya/Jovial samvat, however the methodology of determining it is radically different from the past.

The Vishnudharmottara Purana linked the Jovian samvats with naksatras, but the modern method based on Brihat Samhita, links it's with numerology associated with the Saka/Vikrama years. And there is a radical difference in reckoning of Jovian samvats between North India & South India.

great info.  but my question is when did Hindus conceptualize time as a linear arrow going from the past to the future without notions of cycles and since when did they start dating events on a linear calendar? @অনু
